# Domain’s NS accessible via IPv6 only

Tags: domain-name-system, ipv6

Imagine a level-2 domain where some (albeit not all) NSes haven’t any A record but have AAAA instead. In other words, some NSes are accessible via IPv6 only. Ī mean, something like:

```
@         IN    SOA     example.net. root.example.net.
;
@         IN    NS      commercial.DNS.example.
@         IN    NS      homebrew
homebrew  IN    AAAA    2001:db8::c001:5eff
service   IN    A       198.51.100.3
service   IN    AAAA    2001:db8::c000:0001
```

- Which (if any) public TLDs permit for such subdomain configuration?
- Will a significant portion of DNS queries, pertaining to the domain, be served by IPv6-only servers?
- How accessible (from the Internet) will the domain be if all IPv4 NSes went offline but IPv6-only ones continued?

Or, to make a conclusion, is a IPv6-only NS anywhere better than not having such NS at all? All questions consider nowadays (as of 2015) Internet.

Comment: While I appreciate the skillful use of RFC-approved documentation addresses and names, I'm not seeing what the actual problem is.  This can't really be answered.  For example, the number of DNS requests you receive is going to be based on how many people are requesting DNS records.

Comment: @Hyppy: Ī clarified my second question.

Comment: I'm starting to think this is a homework question.

Comment: @Hyppy: because Ī demonstrated a suspicious (for a random Internet loiterer) skill in writing documentation-like texts? [This](https://tools.wmflabs.org/quentinv57-tools/tools/sulinfo.php?username=Incnis+Mrsi) will shed light to this mysterious phenomenon, for you.

Comment: No, the reason is because StackExchange is used for looking for solutions to a particular *problem* rather than asking for opinions on a generic question. While it's a good question, it's not really suitable in our Q&A format.

Comment: I don't think this sounds like a homework question. It sounds like a sysadmin that has been asked to solve one of those odd-ball operational problems that crops up.

Comment: Do you know what will definitely not get your question re-opened? Editing it so that there isn't even a question at all.

Comment: On my opinion, your question was a good one and shouldn't have been closed. But there is a voting system here and sometimes they decide into the wrong way. Not very often, but these are really annoying. The only what I can do is that I now revert your question to its previous state and nominate to reopen. Maybe you could have a better luck on http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Agreed with @peterh. It's closed because people found it way too broad for a Q&A site and is more "best practice" or "concept" than an actual problem. Other sites may be more receptive.

Comment: @NathanC 1) It is not clear to me why where the "best practice" or "concept" question problematic. Everybody could answer his own "best practice", and  then the community voted which is better. Factual questions are often also "opinionated", in their case this system works. 2) If it is even so, it should have a different close reason (for example, on the place of the totally useless "control-panels-are-offtopic" reason).

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking is largely opinion based, which isn't a good way to approach the problem. What you should be more concerned with are what the standards have to say. Considering the fact that nothing has emerged to obsolete [BCP91](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3901), I think you would be best served by reading the document in full. [Section 1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3901#section-1) explains the problem in detail, but to avoid quoting the entire RFC here I'm going to skip ahead to the conclusions reached in [section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3901#section-4):

> 4. DNS IPv6 Transport recommended Guidelines
>
> In order to preserve name space continuity, the following
> administrative policies are recommended:
>
> ```
>   - every recursive name server SHOULD be either IPv4-only or dual
>     stack,
>
>      This rules out IPv6-only recursive servers.  However, one might
>      design configurations where a chain of IPv6-only name server
>      forward queries to a set of dual stack recursive name server
>      actually performing those recursive queries.
>
>   - every DNS zone SHOULD be served by at least one IPv4-reachable
>     authoritative name server.
>
>      This rules out DNS zones served only by IPv6-only authoritative
>      name servers.
> ```
>
> Note: zone validation processes SHOULD ensure that there is at
> least    one IPv4 address record available for the name servers of any
> child    delegations within the zone.

The word "SHOULD" is used here, so no one is explicitly forbidden from deviating away from this BCP, but it's still a really bad idea. Even if several MSOs have transitioned to making their DNS servers IPv6 enabled, the amount of traffic that you would be forfeiting from the internet is somewhat ludicrous. That's an opinion obviously, but consider this: Google's public DNS service does not communicate with IPv6 servers at all unless you submit a query over IPv6. The majority of traffic submitted to them is over IPv4, and the infrastructure responsible for those queries *does not* talk to IPv6 DNS servers.

If you need one iron clad reason for why this is a bad idea, there you have it. But the larger concern really should be "too many DNS servers won't talk to you for this to be a realistic design decision".

Comment: Well, nameservers of ISPs do recursion, they might be “dual stack”, and hence Ī expect them to query my hypothetical IPv6-only servers. Do you realize your lengthy quote does not address the question?

By the way, why are you sure that my IPv6-only server will not have IPv4? Ī said it will **not have A records**, i.e. inaccessible via IPv4 **from the Internet.** It can have an IPv4 connection in LAN with a RFC-1918 address and, hence, perfectly can do recursion (for its local clients) via upstream NSes and/or NAT.

Comment: Not all ISPs currently do, and the Google example demonstrates that not all of those who are capable of doing so will. Creating an interoperability problem with clients who use Google's open IPv4 resolvers is tantamount to operator self-sabotage. As for not providing `A` records, I've already directed you toward reading the first section of BCP91. The quoted section is the conclusion reached: all DNS zones SHOULD have an IPv4 reachable nameserver (`A` record glue). You can argue the BCP if you like, but most professional DNS operators will not.

Comment: Ī saved the thread [here](http://www.superstructure.info/StackExchange/serverfault/domain-s-ns-accessible-via-ipv6-only.html) and now am going to deface the question. The only upvote is mine.

Answer (score 2):

All TLDs should support this, however for the near future having a DNS server with a v6 only address would have too many limitations.

Comment: Elaborate, please. List 2–3 **concrete** limitations. Otherwise it looks like an opinion, not an expert assessment.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi I don't think people here are going to do your homework for you.

Comment: It is an opinion- from an expert- there is no set answer here

Answer (score 2):

> Which (if any) public TLDs permit for such subdomain configuration?

They all should.  However some *registrars* may prevent it due to restrictions in their web UIs.  You should consider this a bug and complain. It would be useful if you reported any registrars you find doing this.

> How many DNS requests, pertaining to the domain, will be served by IPv6-only servers?

Most DNS servers that are configured for IPv6, filter out any AAAA records if the request came from IPv4. This is done as a precaution so that misconfigured IPv4-only hosts don't try to connect via AAAA.  In other words, if a host is able to reach the DNS server via IPv6, then it is safe to tell the user to connect via IPv6 too.   Sites like Google did this when they enabled IPv6; I'm not sure if they've stopped doing it since ["World IPv6 Day"](http://www.worldipv6launch.org/).

> How accessible (from the Internet) will the domain be if all IPv4 NSes went offline but IPv6-only ones continued?

I don't know.  In theory, some DNS servers may be doing their queries under IPv6, but most likely very few. However I can suggest a test that would help you predict the answer.

If I was going to make a change like this, first I would set up an experiment to test the above hypothesis.  For example, set up 2 NS records each with one A record and one AAAA record.  Run in this configuration for a week, keeping logs of the requests you get.  Calculate what % of IPv6 traffic you get. Calculate what % of queries were received via IPv6 but produced answers that did not include AAAA records.

I would do this test no matter what.  There are too many ambiguities in how ISPs configure their DNS servers.

Comment: The claim that `Most DNS servers that are configured for IPv6, filter out any AAAA records if the request came from IPv4.` sounds dubious. The authoritative DNS server cannot know the IP address of the client (unless a non-standard extension is agreed upon between recursor and authoritative), which makes such filtering on authoritative DNS servers mostly impossible. Such filtering on recursive resolvers would be possible, but a violation of the protocol and likely to cause more breakage than it fixes.

Comment: Additionally the claim that `Sites like Google did this when they enabled IPv6` is dubious since Google still does not have IPv6 support on their authoritative servers. So every query they receive will come in over IPv4.

Comment: I may be misremembering it.  Google certainly did implement the whitelist.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_brokenness_and_DNS_whitelisting#DNS_whitelisting   The "delete AAAA records to IPv4 clients" thing may have been a brainstorm that was later rejected (or it was something done experimentally).  however, the brokenness was real (cite: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_brokenness_and_DNS_whitelisting#Brokenness) and until World IPv6 Day, ISPs did a lot of weird things to work around it.   After IPv6 Day, the solution is to tell the client to fix themselves.

Comment: The brokenness was indeed real. It was mostly fixed around 2010. Google did indeed use a whitelist of **resolvers** which got to see AAAA records. That whitelist contained the IPv4 addresses of resolvers at ISPs with solid dual stack deployments. The whitelists were in use until mid 2012.

Comment: Ī saved the thread [here](http://www.superstructure.info/StackExchange/serverfault/domain-s-ns-accessible-via-ipv6-only.html) and now am going to deface the question. Thanks for your efforts (the only upvote is mine).